# Proving that $g_nf_n$ converges to $0$ in measure on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question: Let $f_n,g_n:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be measurable functions.  Assume $f_n\rightarrow 0$ in measure on $[0,1]$, and that $\int g_ndx<1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Prove that $g_nf_n\rightarrow 0$ in measure on $[0,1]$

My thoughts: So, we are trying to show that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $\forall n>N$, we have $m\{|g_nf_n-gf|>\epsilon\}<\epsilon$.  So, I was going to try and show convergence pointwise a.e. to then imply convergence in measure, but that fell apart.  So, would I go about this by setting up integrals and splitting the integral bounds?

Any help, suggestions, tips, etc. are (as always!) greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: There is no $gf$ here. I think that part should be fixed.  Doing so will actually make a signficant step towards the proof.

Comment: PS: Convergence pointwise almost everywhere is stronger than you need and does not always hold in this situation. It is best to just use the definition of convergence in measure.

Comment: Ah, since we are trying to show convergence in measure to $0$, then we should be just trying to show $m\{|g_nf_n|>\epsilon\}<\epsilon$, right?  Is there a nice way to split up the $f_n$ and $g_n$ without breaking any rules?

Comment: Fix $\epsilon>0$.  For any $\delta>0$ we have: 
$$\{|g_nf_n|>\epsilon\} \subseteq \{|f_n|>\delta\} \cup \{|g_n| \delta > \epsilon\}$$

Comment: From there, since $f_n\rightarrow 0$ on $[0,1]$, we wouldn't really be concerned with $\{|f_n|>\delta\}$, right?  For the $g_n$ piece, could we say that since $g_n$ is integrable and the integral is less than $1$ for all $n$, then the biggest that the $\{|g_n|\delta>\epsilon\}$ piece would get is $\delta$, and as $\delta\rightarrow 0$, we get the result?

Comment: Yes the $m(\{|f_n|>\delta\})$ gets very small with $n$.  For the measure of $\{|g_n|>\epsilon/\delta\}$  you would need to use an explicit bound on the measure that involves the integral.

Comment: Okay... so that bound could be formed using Chebychev's inequality, like line 3 of Oliver's proof below, right?

Comment: It is just the Markov inequality, actually.  It seems the Oliver proof is choosing $\delta = \epsilon^2$. I would have chosen $\delta = \epsilon^2/2$ but it is essentially the same thing. Or you can apply the Markov inequality directly to $m(\{|g_n|>\epsilon/\delta\})$ and then choose $\delta$ later.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see.  I really appreciate your help.  I am having quite a tough time finding some examples of in measure, pointwise a.e., and uniform convergence besides in very general terms, so I really do appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\lambda(|f_ng_n|>\varepsilon)&=\lambda(|f_ng_n|>\varepsilon,|f_n|>\varepsilon^2)+\lambda(|f_ng_n|>\varepsilon,|f_n|\leq\varepsilon^2)\\
&\leq \lambda(|f_n|>\varepsilon^2) + \lambda(\varepsilon^2|g_n|>\varepsilon)\\
&\leq \lambda(|f_n|>\varepsilon^2) + \lambda(|g_n|>\tfrac{1}{\varepsilon})\leq 
\lambda(|f_n|>\varepsilon^2) + \varepsilon\int|g_n|\\
&\leq \lambda(|f_n|>\varepsilon^2) + \varepsilon
\end{align}
$$

Then for all $n$ large enough, say $n\geq N_\varepsilon$,
$$\lambda(|f_ng_n|>\varepsilon)\leq 2\varepsilon$$
This implies that $g_nf_n$ converges to $0$ in measure. To see this, let $\delta>0$. Choose $\varepsilon<\delta$ and let $N_\varepsilon$ be as above. Then
$\lambda(|f_ng_n|>\delta)\leq \lambda(|f_ng_n|>\varepsilon)\leq2\varepsilon$ for all $n\leq n\geq M_\varepsilon$. This shows that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(|f_ng_n|>\delta)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since convergence in measure is equivalent the fact that every subsequence has  a further  subsequence converging almost everywhere we can reduce the proof to the case where $f_n$ tends to $0$ almost everywhere.

With this change the result can be proved easily using Egoroff's Theorem. Choose $E$ such that $f_n \to 0$ unifromly on $E$ and $\mu (E^{c}) <\epsilon$. Choose $n_0$ such that $ f_n(x) <\epsilon ^{2}$ for all $x \in E$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Now $\mu (f_ng_n >\epsilon) \leq \epsilon + \mu (E \cap (f_ng_n >\epsilon))\leq \epsilon+\mu (g_n >\frac 1 {\epsilon}) \leq \epsilon+\epsilon \int g_n d\mu<2\epsilon$.

Comment: I think you meant $\mu(E^c\cap(f_ng_n>\varepsilon))$ in your sequence of inequalities.

Comment: Both comments above are misplaced. I have chosen $E$ such that $\mu (E^{c}) <\epsilon$ and $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on$E$, not the other way around.